# Hide annotation subtitle, or change color

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

In my app am adding subtitle to annotation pin but don't want to show with pin. I am just using it for coding purpose. How can I hide or change subtitle color?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are using pin subtitle for some processing and doesn't want to show it on pin. If you are using default callout then it is not possible to change colour of subtitle or to hid it once you assign `annotation.subtitle = @"some subtitle"`.

I would suggest, add another variable to annotation and assign subtitle to that variable (`annotation.newSubtitle = @"some subtitle"`)and don't assign anything for subtitle attribute. All the processing you want to do then can be done with  `annotation.newSubtitle`.

If you are reluctant to add new variable to annotation then you will have to implement custom callout which is tedious.

**EDIT**:
You will find following useful to assign NSString to your annotation.

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
NSString *newSubTitle;
}
@property(retain,readwrite, nonatomic) NSString *newSubTitle ;
@end
```

In implementation part

```
@implementation MyAnnotation
@synthesize mSubTitle;
-(void)setNewSubTitle:(NSString *)SubTitle{
    self.newSubTitle  = SubTitle;
}
@end
```

And for assigning

```
[annotation setNewSubTitle: @"some text"];
```

for accessing

```
myString = annotation.newSubtitle
```

Comment: im getting warning 
Semantic Issue: Method '-newSubtitle' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

at this line 



pinView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%d.png",[[annotation newSubtitle] integerValue]]];

Comment: @pallavi, probably you need to implement -(void)setNewSubTitle:(NSString *)SubTitle method. See updated answer. if you have any difficulty let me know.

Comment: it dosent work for me. unable to access newSubtitle in
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation

Comment: newSubTitle (or any other assigned variable to MKAnnotation) will not be accessible (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation method. But there are several other methods in which you can access and use it. for example you can assign newSubTitle at time of creating annoation. annotation.newSubTitle = @"new subt";

Answer (score 1):

If you want access any string for every specific annotation, you can use NSMutableDictionary and add your annotation as key. and later you could access this in

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
```